# Why does one element stays in original list when selection sorting?

Tags: c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int val;
    struct node* next;
    } ;

struct node* largest(struct node** first)
{
    struct node* largest = *first;
    struct node* prev = NULL;
    struct node* temp_prev = NULL;

    for(;first != NULL; first = first -> next)
        {
            if (first -> val > largest -> val)  
                {
                    largest = first;
                    prev = temp_prev;
                }          
            temp_prev = first;
        }
        if(prev != NULL)
        prev -> next = largest -> next;
        largest -> next = NULL;
        return largest;            
}


struct node* sel_sort(struct node** list)
{
    struct node* head = NULL;
    struct node* temp_largest = NULL;
    while (*list)
    {   
        head = largest(list);
        head->next=temp_largest;
        temp_largest = head;

    }
    *list = head; // note sets the input pointer to the new list.
    return head;
}

void print_list(struct node* first)
{
    struct node* temp;
    for (temp = first; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
    {
        printf("%d\n", temp->val);
    }
}

void main() {
    struct node* r = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* s = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* t = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* w = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* q = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    r->val = 2;
    r->next = s;
    s->val = 10;
    s->next = t;
    t->next = w;
    t->val = 3;
    w->val = 1;
    w->next = q;
    q->val = 6;
    q->next = NULL;
    printf("\nBefore Sort:\n");
    print_list(r);
    printf("\nSorted:\n");
    struct node* sorted = sel_sort(&r);
    print_list(sorted);
    }
```

In short, the above is selection sort for a singly linked list. I'm having an issue where an infinite loops occurs in the sel_sort method, because no matter how many times I call the largest method, one node will be left in the original list. Other then that my code seems to work, but how do I get around this small problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what do you expect will *ever* modify the variable `list` in this while-loop:

```
struct node* temp = *list;
struct node* head;
struct node* temp_largest = NULL;
while (list != NULL) // <<=== infinite loop
{   
    head = largest(temp);
    head->next=temp_largest;
    temp_largest = head;

}
return head;
```

I question your use of `temp`. Technically your `largest()` function should take a list head by address (pointer to pointer), extract the largest node, returning that node after removal from the list, and updating the passed-in list head on the off-chance it was the *first* node in the list (therefore the head has to be moved):

```
struct node* head = NULL;
struct node* temp_largest = NULL;
while (*list)
{   
    head = largest(list);
    head->next=temp_largest;
    temp_largest = head;

}
*list = head; // note sets the input pointer to the new list.
return head;
```

And have `largest()` take a list pointer by address (a double pointer)

```
struct node* largest(struct node** first)
{
    struct node *prev = NULL;
    struct node *lprev = NULL;
    struct node *cur = NULL;
    struct node *largest = NULL;

    if (!(first && *first))
        return NULL;

    // assume the first node is the largest node
    largest = lprev = prev = *first;
    cur = largest->next;
    for(; cur; prev = cur, cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->val > largest->val)
        {
            largest = cur;
            lprev = prev;
        }
    }

    // go with the simple stuff first. was `largest`
    //  the first item in the list?
    if (largest == *first)
    {
        // yes it was, so move the list head.
        *first = largest->next;
    }
    else
    {   // no it was not, so link `lprev` to be
        //  the node following `largest`
        lprev->next = largest->next;
    }

    // regardless. always unlink the largest node.
    largest->next = NULL;
    return largest;
}
```

Using this in combination with the updated sort, I get this for output:

**Output**

```
Before Sort:
2
10
3
1
6

Sorted:
1
2
3
6
10
```

Comment: head = largest(temp);

If you look, this removes a node form the list, and it works up until there is only one node left. Thats why its stuck but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Edit: look at the largest function

Comment: Oh man I just got that, I forgot about referencing it as a pointer,let me try it out thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSwiecki Update coming, it is how your `largest()` extracts the node from the original list.

Comment: Hmm, still infinite loop, when I tested it with print statements, I found one element tends to remain in the original list and never gets removed.

Comment: I will paste my entire code including the calls main makes, I might be making this unclear. From the old list, what I am trying to do is pop the largest valued node, and keep doing that forming a newly sorted list. I keep calling largest until there are no elements left in the original list but the last node never gets popped giving me an infinite loop in the while statement.

Comment: @JonathanSwiecki I know exactly what your trying to do. Implement `largest()` as I described above, and use it with the code in the last post. It should do precisely what you want. Note: it is *very* important when `largest()` is handed the address of a list pointer with one item that is return the one item and set the in/out parameter (dbl-pointer) to NULL.

Comment: Alright, I started programming just over a month ago so bear with me haha. Just need to thoroughly reread your post.

Comment: I implemented it how you said but since largest takes a double pointer, how do I make the rest of the function cope? I'm sorry if this is troublesome, I understand pointers just fine, but when it comes to double pointers I am almost completely lost.

Comment: @JonathanSwiecki You're actually doing pretty well considering you've only been at this a month. Double-pointers are just like single pointers save for the *type* of the thing they point to. Just like an `int *p` is a pointer to an `int`, an `int **pp` is a pointer to a pointer (to an int =P). As soon as you rap your head around the idea that a "pointer to" something is itself a *type* (like `int`) the easier it will be to digest. I'll take a look at your largest() function and let you know what I come up with.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to wrap my head around recursion and get a better grasp on pointers by making simple sorting algorithms. Strangely I had much less problems with my quicksort.

Comment: @JonathanSwiecki there ya go. I just ran it through your test program (by the way `void main()` is non-standard. it should return an `int`, specifically EXIT_SUCCESS on a good exit, EXIT_FAILURE on abnormal termination). Give the posted `largest()` a try.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'm going to look at it and see why mine was wrong. thanks a ton!